# Size of a set defined by divisor function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, divisors-multiples

After some computations, I guessed the following conjecture. 
How can I prove or disprove it? thanks!

Let

$$
A(k)=\#\left\{\left(t,\frac{k+t+a}{4t-1}\right):1\leq t\leq k,\ 1\leq a\leq k+t,\ a\mid(k+t)^2\right\}.
$$

Then
$$
A(k)\sim c k\log k\log\log k
$$
for some $c>0$. Also it seems that $c=1$.

Comment: Your definition of $A(k)$ is rather unclear. Do you really count pairs $(t,\ast)$, or you are interested in the number of distinct values of $t$? Also, how did you manage to distinguish computationally between $\log\log k$ and, say, $\log\log\log k$?

Comment: Why use the ordered pair $(t,\frac{k+t+a}{4t-1})$? For a fixed $k$, such ordered pairs are in 1-to-1 correspondence with $(t,a)$ itself, so why not just count those? Are you trying to imply that you require $4t-1$ to divide $k+t+a$? Otherwise $A(k)$ simply equals $\sum_{t=1}^k \frac{\tau((k+t)^2)+1}2$, which might have order of magnitude more like $k\log^2k$, by analogy with $\sum_{n\le x} \tau(n^2)$.

Comment: @GregMartin, Exactly! your summation formula is true :) thanks. Could you please explain a little bit how did you come to this formula? If I need to count those $A(k)$ that also $4t-1|k+t+a$ how can I do that?

Comment: @Seva, It was just a guess using the behavior of the cardinality of $A(k)$ by Mathematica. Maybe I was wrong.